# DateTime::createFromFormat month name

Tags: php, datetime

I'm using `DateTime::createFromFormat` in PHP like this:

```
$month = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", '2014-08-01');
```

But `echo $month` is showing up as 08. How can I display it as a 3 letter name, i.e.: Aug?

Comment: You question is bogus... You are saying that `echo $month` is returning `08`, which is not possible, since `$month = DateTime::...` returns `DateTime instance` or `false`. Can you fix your question, so it make more sense? [Is this what you are looking for?](https://eval.in/208613).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use capital M instead of m .

```
  $getMonth = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", '2014-08-01');
```

If you already have the date variable created then you  can use directly the below code

```
 $month = $getMonth->format('M');
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Vijay I'll go ahead and accept in a couple of minutes once I can.

Comment: -1: this is just wrong! This doesn't even work. @DT.DTDG: why did you accept this answer?

Comment: The date format doesn't match the date string supplied. After this code is run $month === false.